# UV Unwrap a cylinder in arc

Tags: texturing, materials, scripting, uv, add-on

I used a cylinder to make a paper cup. Now I need to unwrap the cylinder in an arc form as shown in the image. The default wrap doesn't fit properly. Scaling & rotating also doesn't fit it properly.
[image: UV Unwrap (wireframe)]

I have the this in format Autocad(.dwg, .dxf), CorelDraw(.cdr, .eps).
The cylinder is also of 32 sides as in the drawing.

Currently, I use to pick & place each vertex in the UV editor as shown below,
[image: Required]
Is there an addon or python script that can help?
Ps: I need to do this for various sizes so any help will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you take your tapered, capless cylinder, mark a single seam down the side, and give it a standard (conformal)  <kbd>U</kbd> 'Unwrap', the result will be the arc you are looking for. 'Unwrap' is the first item on the unwrap menu.

This illustration shows the UV map converted to geometry using Geometry Nodes, and uniformly scaled to the exact size of the geometry it maps:

[image]

..showing all the line segments are the same relative length.